# How do I monitor disk activity on a specific drive?

Tags: performance, usb-drive

I'd like to watch disk activity on my USB external hard drive. I know that I can use `iotop` to monitor disk I/O for each running process, but is there a way to get a measure per filesystem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

dstat is better than iostat for strictly monitoring disk activity.

I am running the following command while moving files from one harddrive to another

```
dstat -D sda,sdc
```

for more info, have a look at this page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskPerformance

Comment: Very nice. However this way I can't see which process is causing the IO. So I'm stuck with either seeing which process (with iotop) or which device (with dstat), but not both.

Comment: I wish we could also limit its monitoring to a specific process

Comment: And in contrast to iotop it doesn't even need root.

Comment: Good call @jlh I understand your pain point and I can't think of an easy solution other than understanding your running process. You should know for example that postgresql is installed on a specific drive and has storage on the other one. so, with that knowledge, looking at both iotop and dstat should give you the information you need. hope this helps.

Comment: @Nobody iotop needs root to look into process you do not own. dstat don't need root as devices info is available to normal users under /proc and /sys stats files

Answer (score 24):

I'm not skilled in this area, but *iostat* comes to mind. You can install it with the [sysstat](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/sysstat) package. Good luck!

Comment: example usage:  `iostat -d 10 /dev/sda` will give you the io utilization in 10 second intervals of `/dev/sda`.  I'd almost use `watch iostat -d /dev/sda` over its interval option.  Edit: beat me to it while I was typing :)

Comment: I just read that the first set of values reported are statistics from what has occurred since system startup, so it turns out not to make much sense to use `watch`. Continuous reporting with something like `iostat -dk 10` returns more meaningful numbers.

Comment: Hmm... I just don't like that it fills my entire scrollback.

Comment: Crank open a new terminal and do it then

Answer (score 16):

Using `iostat` from the `sysstat` package provides a single snapshot of results since startup.  Use of the interval parameter will append the results for only the last interval to the output.  Example, `iostat 10` will first show the "since boot" values then continue to add the last 10 seconds of statistics to the output, every 10 seconds.  Include the `-y` option to omit the first display of statistics since boot but understand that the command will appear idle for the specified interval while the system collects the first snapshot.

I've found this most effective when combined with the `watch` command and indicating to only collect for a single interval of statistics.  For example:

```
watch -t -n 0.1 iostat -p sda,sdc -d -t -y 5 1
```

This gives a refresh every 5.1 seconds of activity statistics for the last 5 seconds. To break down the options and parameters...

- The first `-t` tells `watch` to omit the header. This is to avoid confusion that otherwise the header will include "Every 0.1s" which does not represent the snapshot of data.
- The `-n 0.1` tells `watch` to run the following command every 0.1 seconds.  This is the smallest interval for `watch` (`procps-ng 3.3.9`) but don't worry, it isn't actually running the command every 0.1 seconds.  It will run the command 0.1 seconds after the prior instance completes.
- The `-p sda,sdc` tells `iostat` to only display stats for these devices.
- The `-d` tells `iostat` to only display device utilization, relevant since the question was concerning disk activity.
- The second `-t` switch tells `iostat` to include the time of the refresh in the statistics.  This is useful since the earlier omission of the `watch` header removed the time display that would have been there.
- The `-y` switch omits the first screen of "since boot" statistics from the interval display.  Without this the result would be a display of the statistics since boot updating at the interval of the watch command.
- The `5 1` are the `iostat` interval parameters. In this case capture 5 seconds of statistics once (the 1).  Because the `-y` switch was used this will only present a single screen of data.

It will take 5 seconds for `iostat` to collect the data, it will then be displayed in `watch`, and 0.1 seconds later watch will trigger the `iostat` command again.  5 seconds later the new data will replace the old, `watch` will wait 0.1 seconds, wash, rinse, repeat...

Answer (score 14):

Try with *nmon*

```
sudo apt-get install nmon
```

Try:

```
nmon
```

Output Like below:

[image]

Press d = Disk Press c = CPU Press r = RAM, Press v = Virtual Memory, Kernal Status press K, Press N = network  and Press q or x to exit

Answer (score 2):

In order to monitor disk IO per device and process in one glance, consider using `glances`.

https://nicolargo.github.io/glances

You can install it with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install glances
```

or `pip`:

```
pip install glances
```

Comment: Best answer. Glances replaces iotop+dstat